# Getting multiple requests in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple voting system (Yes or No) if you click Yes the state needs to be a string **up** and if you click No the state needs to be **down**, the vote works fine in the **voteHandler** method, but the problem is that i have to refresh the page everytime i vote so i can see the vote changes! i have added the useEffect so the vote changes directly but when i did i got alot of requests and errors, for example, i have 5 questions and each question might have multiple answers and each answer has the vote component (Yes or No), the requests = the number of questions * the number of answers!!

Here is the component without useEffect :

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import {AnswerContext} from './AnswerWrapper';

const AnswerItem = (props) => {

    let indexPlus;

    const indexCount = (index) => {
        indexPlus = index;
        return indexPlus;
    }

    const { active, setActive } = useContext(AnswerContext)

    const [vote, setVote] = useState();

    const voteHandler = (e, index, value) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setActive(index);
        setVote(value)
        // I am sending this to a parent component
        props.onVote ({
            vote : value,
            answerID : index
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={(e) => voteHandler(e, props.index, 'up')}>Yes <span>({props.ups !== null ? props.ups : 0 })</span></button>
            <button onClick={(e) => voteHandler(e, props.index, 'down')}>No <span>({props.downs !== null ? props.downs : 0 })</span></button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default AnswerItem;
```

And here is the component with useEffect :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import {AnswerContext} from './AnswerWrapper';

const AnswerItem = (props) => {

    let indexPlus;

    const indexCount = (index) => {
        indexPlus = index;
        return indexPlus;
    }

    const { active, setActive } = useContext(AnswerContext)

    const [vote, setVote] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        props.onVote ({
            vote : vote,
            answerID : active
        })
    }, [vote, active])

    const voteHandler = (e, index, value) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setActive(index);
        setVote(value)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={(e) => voteHandler(e, props.index, 'up')}>Yes <span>({props.ups !== null ? props.ups : 0 })</span></button>
            <button onClick={(e) => voteHandler(e, props.index, 'down')}>No <span>({props.downs !== null ? props.downs : 0 })</span></button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default AnswerItem;
```

And to make it a bit clear, here is the parent component of **AnswerItem**

```
import React, { useContext, useCallback } from 'react';
import AnswerItem from './AnswerItem';

const AccordionItem = (props) => {

    const handleVote = (dataV) => {
        props.voteChanged(dataV)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {props.answers.map((data, index) => (
                <AnswerItem key={index} index={data.id} ups={data.ups} downs={data.downs} onVote={handleVote} />
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default AccordionItem;
```

And lastly here is my App.js code, i didn't mention above that i post the votes in my API **Api.postVote**  :

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import AccordionItem from './components/AccordionItem';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          questions: [],
        };
    }
    handleVoteData = (dataV) => {
        this.sendVoteUpsData(dataV)
    }
    sendVoteUpsData = (dataV) => {
        let newData = {...this.state};
        newData.params = {
            client_id : this.props.client,
            the_vote : dataV.vote,
            the_answerID : dataV.answerID
        }
        Api.postVote(newData.params)
        .then( response => {
            if(response.data.status === 'success'){
                return response.data.data;
            }
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div>
                    {
                        this.state.questions.map((data, index) => (
                            <AccordionItem answers={data.answers} voteChanged={this.handleVoteData}/>
                        ))
                    }
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you do not need to use useEffect hook to trigger props.onVote method, the first code should work.

Second, you don't see vote changes because your component has to rerender after the vote happened, and in order to make your component **AnswerItem** rerender, the object that contains {ups & downs} should be a state of the parent component for example.

see below code snippet and you will get the idea

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import AnswerItem from './AnswerItem';

const AnswerWrapper = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({ ups: { '1': 3 }, downs: { '1': 0 } })

    const onVote = ({ vote, answerID }) => {
        if (vote == 'up') {
            setState({ ...state, ups: { ...state.ups, [answerID]: state.ups[answerID] + 1 } })
        } else if (vote == 'down') {
            setState({ ...state, downs: { ...state.downs, [answerID]: state.downs[answerID] + 1 } })
        }
    }

    return (
        <AnswerItem onVote={onVote} index={'1'} ups={state.ups['1']} downs={state.downs['1']} />
    )

}

export default AnswerWrapper;
```

I assumed the above component is the parent, and since the ups and downs in the state, so any changes will rerender the component, then the **AnswerItem** component will re-render accordingly.

The idea is your component has to be re rendered.

Comment: Tks, i get your solution, but it's a bit confusing because i am posting the votes in API so i couldn't adapt it using your solution, i have updated the code if u could check it!

Comment: in the AccordionItem component, you are receiving a property called "Answers" but I couldn't see that you are passing Answers in the App component.
please correct your code.

Comment: Yes! i have updated the code

Comment: Ok, assuming that the postVote method pushes the answers to the server then the server responses with the updated questions and answers, then instead of return response.data.data, use this.setState({...this.state, questions: response.data.data})
this is going to make your components rerender.

Comment: Can you update this part of code?

Comment: try yourself, if postVote returns back the updated questions with answers, remove return response.data.data and write this.setState({...this.state, questions: response.data.data}).